# Python name files to its corresponding value in a csv

Tags: python, csv, filenames

Let's say I have a csv file with two columns:

```
HEX;TITLE
0xAB;BN4
0xAC;ZF4
0xAD;ET6
```

I have a python script that reads the csv and transforms each hex to a photo, and writes it to a jpeg. This is the script so you can see what it does:

```
import binascii
import os

count = 0

with open('photos.txt', 'r') as f:
    for i in f:

        count = count + 1

        photo = i[2:]

        cleaned = photo.strip("\r\n")

        transform = binascii.a2b_hex(cleaned)

        with open("{}.jpg".format(count), 'wb') as output:
            output.write(transform)

f.close()
```

The count in my script gives the file a name and it is incremental. In the folder I will see: 1.jpeg, 2.jpeg, 3.jpeg and so on.

But my question is: How do I name those files to its corresponding TITLE-value in the csv? So that the first file will be BN4.jpeg, and the second file ZF4.jpeg?

FYI: the input file has currently one column containing the hex for the script above.

Answer (score 0):

use the `csv` module to get 2 separate fields. No need to `strip`, just unpack the data while reading:

```
with open('photos.csv', 'r') as f:
    cr = csv.reader(f,delimiter=";")
    for photo,filename in cr:

        transform = binascii.a2b_hex(photo[2:])

        with open("{}.jpg".format(filename), 'wb') as output:
            output.write(transform)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I need to remove the 0x from the hex and the carriage return, so I have to strip and clean it. I don't have it working at the moment, it gives an odd-length string error so the hex isn't properly given to binascii.